# Depict vs Express

Tags: difference

The artists wanted to express/depict real life, to paint straight from nature.

Depict seems more natural, but do we have a better explanation for why one and not the other?

Comment: Did you consult a dictionary first? The definitions are quite clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I associate *depict* with painting, drawing or other form of art. This word is a good choice since they are artists, and they are going to paint.

*Express* is a commonplace word meaning *convey emotions/thoughts*, and is rarely used when you want to sound sophisticated.

Answer (score 1):

***Depict*** specifically means to explain something through an **art form** like drawing, painting etc.

***Express*** is a more general term that means to explain something via your **behavior, feelings or words.**

Answer (score 0):

Express is used to express something like feelings, opinions.(something that we cannot see)

> e.g
>    I want to express my views on this subject.

**Depict** is used to show something physically.
 Usually living things express and non living depict.